# Meteor Mongo Aggregate $lookup specify output field

Tags: mongodb, meteor, aggregation-framework

I have two collections: Products and Stocks.
The relation between these two collections is one to one.

Products structure:

```
{
_id:
sku: 
....
}
```

Stocks structure :

```
{
_id:
sku:
availability: []
....
}
```

My query:

```
Products.aggregate([
        {
          $match: cAux
        }, {
          $lookup: {
            from: "Stocks",
            localField: "sku",
            foreignField: "sku",
            as: "availability"
          }
        }, {
          $sort: PRODUCT_SORT
        }
      ]);
```

The result from this "join" is

```
{
_id:
sku: 
availability: {_id:, sku:, **availabity**: []}
...
}
```

The join is okay, but I would like to only have the availability array field being joined and not the whole Stock document. Whats the best way to accomplish this? Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: So it looks like you just need to output a specific field from Stock collection ? If yes, you can use {$addFields:{"availability":"$availability.availability"}}

Comment: @Veeram unfortunately that operation is not available at my mongo version. But I found a work around. I posted it as correct answer. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

**Solution**

```
Products.aggregate([
        {
          $match: cAux
        }, {
          $lookup: {
            from: "Stocks",
            localField: "sku",
            foreignField: "sku",
            as: "availability"
          }
        }, {
          $project: {
            ...PRODUCT_FIELDS,
            availability: {
              $arrayElemAt: ['$availability.availability', 0]
            }
          }
        }, {
          $sort: PRODUCT_SORT
        }
      ]);
```